# Comparision of 2 Files using Perl

Tags: perl, oracle11g

Currently i have a requirement for comparing 2 tables each table having around 700M + records.

We have come up with a idea to compare in the File based rather than taking it to the DB , based upon our DB performance. Also heard that Perl is much faster than any other coding method

We need to compare for a Mobile number the Usage plan in one File to the same mobile Number in another File, either if present and its usage is matching or not , we need to write in a new file only the Not matching records.

Example:

File 1

```
number, Usage type , Usage Plan , Usage Volume (KB)  ........
12344 , CP         , FB         , 100  ........
12323 , UP         , FB         , 200  ........
12322 , CP         , G+         , 300  ........
```

File 2

```
number, Usage type , Usage Plan , Usage Volume (KB)  ........
12344 , CP         , FB         , 100  ........
12323 , UP         , FB         , 210  ........
```

So in the above case my unmatch File should contain

Unmatch File

```
12323 , UP         , FB         , 210  ........
12322 , CP         , G+         , 300  ........
```

`........` Means there are many columns after this, which we will not be using to compare. They are rather like more details about the plan.

Please share your suggestions and coding idea on this.

Our aim is to complete the comparison within 6 - 7 hours.. so that loading and other things can be completed within 2 days..

Thanks in Advance..
Sam

Comment: What have you tried? Also, is each line in file 1 guaranteed to exist in file 2?  Are records in each file in the same order?

Comment: Its not guaranteed that it will exist and also they will not be in sorted order.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to specify what problem you have encountered.

Comment: I'd use *Beyond Compare*. Its data comparison mode will match up records by a key field (or fields) of your specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
use strict;

open FILE1, 'file1.txt';
open FILE2, 'file2.txt';
open OUTPUT, '>output.txt';

my $regex = qr/^ *(\d+) , (.*) , (.*) , (\d+)/;

my $file1;
while(<FILE1>){
  if(/$regex/){
    $file1->{$1}->{type} = $2;
    $file1->{$1}->{plan} = $3;
    $file1->{$1}->{volume} = $4;
  }
}

my $file2;
while(<FILE2>){
  if(/$regex/){
    $file2->{$1}->{type} = $2;
    $file2->{$1}->{plan} = $3;
    $file2->{$1}->{volume} = $4;
  }
}

my $numbers;
$numbers->{$_} = 1 foreach keys %$file1;
$numbers->{$_} = 1 foreach keys %$file2;

my $output;
foreach(keys %$numbers){
  if(defined $file1->{$_} && defined $file2->{$_}){
    if($file1->{$_}->{type} ne $file2->{$_}->{type} || $file1->{$_}->{plan} ne $file2->{$_}->{plan} || $file1->{$_}->{volume} ne $file2->{$_}->{volume}){
      push @$output, [$_, $file2->{$_}->{type}, $file2->{$_}->{plan}, $file2->{$_}->{volume}];
    }
  }elsif(defined $file1->{$_}){
    push @$output, [$_, $file1->{$_}->{type}, $file1->{$_}->{plan}, $file1->{$_}->{volume}];
  }else{
    push @$output, [$_, $file2->{$_}->{type}, $file2->{$_}->{plan}, $file2->{$_}->{volume}];
  }
}

print OUTPUT join(' , ', @$_)."\n" foreach @$output;
```

Comment: The solution I presented works for static files and continuously modified files. If you execute the code in a specific time you will get the output of that specific time. When a file changes, then you should execute again in order to have the new output. You could automate this with "cron" under Linux or "Scheduled Tasks" (and friends) under Windows

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that does not read the entire files into memory, which may be problem due to memory constraint. For instance, 700M record x 30 byte/rec = 21GB files.

It does requires the file to be sorted by the number when exported from DB. Assuming the number are increasing.

```
open FILE1, "file1";
open FILE2, "file2";
open OUT, ">out.txt";

$line1 = <FILE1>;
$line2 = <FILE2>;

sub number_part {
    ($line) = @_;
    return $1 if $line =~ /^(\d{1..9})/;
}

while (1) {
    if ($line1 eq $line2) {
        $line1 = <FILE1>;
        $line2 = <FILE2>;

    } elsif ( number_part(line1) == number_part(line2) ) {
        print OUT $line1;
        print OUT $line2;
        $line1 = <FILE1>;
        $line2 = <FILE2>;

    } elsif ( number_part($line1) < number_part($line2) ) {
        print OUT $line1;
        $line1 = <FILE1>;

    } elsif ( number_part(line1) > number_part(line2) ) {
        print OUT $line2;
        $line2 = <FILE2>;
    }

    # Use a dummy record if EOF is reached for either file.
    # Done when EOF is reached for both files.
    $line1 = "9999999999" unless $line1;
    $line2 = "9999999999" unless $line2
    last if $line eq "999999999" and $line2 eq "9999999999";
}

close(FILE1); 
close(FILE2); 
close(OUT);
```